# Delete dynamic element using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Recently i tried to create dynamic elements and try to delete them. the problem is, every time i want to delete a specific element, the one get remove is the very first created element. i already try to use `live()` and `on()` method too. any idea why is this happen? thanks for help

```
<body>
<h2>To Do List</h2>
<div id="inputfield">
    <input type="text" placeholder="add here" id="input">
    <button onclick="addlist()">Add</button>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
```

```
addlist = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    let html = '';
    html += `<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: row" class="main">
                <div id="list">
                    <span id="isilist">` + input + `</span>
                </div>
                <div id="option">
                    <button id="deletebtn">delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>`
    $("#content").append(html)
}

$("#content").on('click', 'button', function(){
    $("#list").remove()
    $("#option").remove()
})
```

or you can try it on https://jsfiddle.net/tLd3kvyo/

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('.main').remove()` .

Comment: IDs **must** be unique, and every delete button you add has the same ID

Comment: maybe you can write the whole code for 'delete' function? i also try to use that but didnt work. thanks @Swati

Comment: Simply write `$("#content").on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).closest('.main').remove()  })` Where `$(this)` is button which you have clicked and `.main` is the div where button is .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was every time you created a new element, they all have the same id="list" hence when you tried removing it, the browser didn't know which id("#list") you were refering to and hence removed the first one. So,
Please change your delete code to this:

```
$("#content").on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

This will remove the button's parent and previous element too.